# All apps crash on click/opening

Tags: crash, launchd, menu-bar

Seeming randomly all applications start to crash. Sometimes after days. This includes Finder and even the Menubar. I've been trying to debug this problem, but so far with no success. Even a full reinstall did not fix the problem. Currently running Big Sur 11.5.2 on Mac Pro 5,1 with OCLP.

**Usage**

I mainly use this Mac to login remotely via SSH or Screen Sharing. And as Plex Server (Home Media Server).

**Symptoms**

- Click running app --> Crash.
- Try to open again --> Crash and
  `Coalition Cache Hit`.

My `system.log` is filled with message like below. I think the biggest clue is in `Coalition Cache Hit` (second to last line). This is shown for any application I try to open. Searching the internet does give some hits, but all are application specific, i.e. "application corrupt/bug". My symptoms are system-wide and across different Big Sur versions.

**Another hint?**

It seems OnyX is the only application not affected. When I start it from the Dock I get a pop up `OnyX requires administrator privileges` to enter my credentials. After that it runs normally.

**Logs**

```
Aug 12 15:30:55 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.spotify.client.startuphelper[17947]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 155: Refusing to execute/trust quarantined program/file: com.spotify.client.startuphelper
Aug 12 15:30:55 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.spotify.client.startuphelper[17947]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
Aug 12 15:30:55 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.spotify.client.startuphelper): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Aug 12 15:30:55 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (application.com.apple.ProblemReporter.1152921500312182616.1152921500312182621[17948]): Service exited due to SIGBUS | sent by exc handler[17948]
Aug 12 15:30:56 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.systemprofiler[17950]): Service exited due to SIGBUS | sent by exc handler[17950]
Aug 12 15:30:56 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.systemprofiler): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
Aug 12 15:30:56 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Finder[17951]): Service exited due to SIGBUS | sent by exc handler[17951]
Aug 12 15:30:56 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.Finder): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
Aug 12 15:30:56 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.screensharing.menuextra[17952]): Service exited due to SIGBUS | sent by exc handler[17952]
Aug 12 15:30:56 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.screensharing.menuextra): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
Aug 12 15:01:07 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.systemprofiler[12629]): Service exited due to SIGBUS | sent by exc handler[12629]
Aug 12 15:01:07 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.systemprofiler): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 1 seconds.
Aug 12 15:01:07 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Coalition Cache Hit: app<application.com.googlecode.iterm2.258218.258224(501)> [1141]
Aug 12 15:01:07 thor com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (application.com.googlecode.iterm2.258218.258224[12630]): Service exited due to SIGBUS | sent by exc handler[12630]
```

**Login session, hint or red herring?**

It also seems something fishy is going on with my login session:

```
~  ps aux | grep -i login
koen             29307   0.0  0.2  4566564  30092   ??  Ss    4:08PM   0:01.03 /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow console
root               136   0.0  0.0  4468908   4424   ??  Ss   10:06AM   0:00.20 /System/Library/CoreServices/logind
koen             29572   0.0  0.0  4268340    572 s000  R+    4:11PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox -i login
```

Compared to a functioning Mac I miss `/usr/libexec/loginitemregisterd` and `login -fp koen` (where koen is my username). Log out, log in does not bring the applications back. So this might be a red herring.

**Crash Reports**

Added a link to some crash reports from `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`:
https://www.dropbox.com/t/PUXHhMAQACUxXxqh

**Tests**

I've run memtest86. It did not return any errors.
Also, ran Apple Hardware Test. I had to swap the original graphics card back in. But then it also ran without any error.

**Replication**

I've not been able to replicate/force the crash.

**Breakthrough?**

This morning I ran `purge` from an SSH session and everything came back to life. I didn't check any stats before running te command. So..? Memory failures, even though memtest and AHT did not show any problems? Run away programs?

Any help getting this sorted is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe run a memory test?

Comment: Can you upload some of the crash reports from `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`?

Comment: @pion per your request I added some reports

Comment: Please create a new admin account on thor and check if you experience the same set of troubles ( app crashing + loginitemregisterd missing ).

Comment: Next run an hardware diagnosis ( I don't like the amount of SIGBUS ).

Comment: I've run memtest86. It did not return any errors.

Comment: I can create a new account. But then I either have to not use the system or configure the account the same as my current account. I think the problem is software related.  I've already reinstalled and build my system backup from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I do have exactly the same problem
Typically if I run Safari the system deteriorated to the point that it crashes and subsequently no apps can be open

Subler and qbitorrent are 2 apps that definitely gets me to the problem. Hackintool is another one

My system is MacPro3,1 running 11.5.2 with OCLP 0.25 NB and latebloom. I have 2 Samsung EVO 970 NVME, 2 HDD, 1 SSD, and external Raid box. Graphic is GTX 680 to 2 x displays

BREAKTHROUGH
I nuked 1 HDD containing Mojave, since then the system seems to perform flawlessly

Comment: That seems a weird solution. How long has your system been stable now?

Comment: ran safari, subler, qbitorrent and so far no issues since, whereas previously, ,running subler and qbitorrent at the same was guaranteed to crash. I think the problem is related to the race conditions we have with bigsur, as was hinted in this conversation: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/opencore-on-the-mac-pro.2207814/post-30167635

Comment: Ah. My problems started before 11.3 which introduced the race condition. Also, the race condition seems to be boot related only.

Comment: race condition do happen on all macos 11 with varying degree of severity. It is mentioned here: https://github.com/StarPlayrX/bigmac/issues/123#issuecomment-879478721

Comment: Fair point about macOS version. Still, working hypothesis is still that the race condition is only in the Boot phase. As mentioned here: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/latebloom-an-experimental-workaround-for-the-11-3-race-condition.2303986/post-30166723

Comment: Give it a try. Diaconnect all disks except your main bigsur disk and see what happens. You have nothing to lose

Comment: i survived 24 hours. no restart, no crash, no problem.

Comment: I've had runs of multiple days before a crash. But crash it will. If I disconnect any hard drives besides my OS drive, the system will be useless. I'd like to have a understanding of why it's crashing before I make changes to the system.

Comment: Make sure your other disk are all in bigsur’s version of apfs. My experience is that when all disk are in bigsur’s apfs, my system become more reliable - booting and running.

Comment: I can now recreate the problem easily:
1. mount disk with apfs-format from mojave
2. do file copy into that disk, or run subler to convert mkv to mp4 to that disk
3. start safari
4. Crashed

Doing the same into bigsur's aps-formatted disk is no problem